# How to dynamically toggle "receiveShadow" in Three.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have a Three.js scene with a simple UI. A checkbox represents the boolean value of an objects `receiveShadow` property. At runtime, when I toggle this checkbox, it does not reflect changes in the scene.

If I do the exact same thing for `castShadow`, it **does** work.

Some import code snippets you might need:
`renderer.shadowMapEnabled = true;`
`material.needsUpdate = true;`

How do I enable this for `receiveShadow`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you dynamically toggle the `receiveShadow` property, you have to set the `needsUpdate` flag for the material.

```
mesh.receiveShadow = true; // or false
mesh.material.needsUpdate = true;
```

The `needsUpdate` flag is then reset to `false` by the renderer.

three.js r.73

Comment: Ok I now added ``mesh.material.needsUpdate = true`` after mesh initialization. However, when I log ``mesh.material``, the ``needsUpdate`` property is always set to ``false``, even though I explicitly set it to ``true``. Any clues?

Comment: The `needsUpdate` flag is reset to `false` after the material is updated by the renderer in `renderer.render()`.

Comment: Ah, this is a gotcha moment for me! I solved the issue by calling ``mesh.material.needsUpdate = true`` after each change. Thank you for the good help @WestLangley

Comment: These sorts of things are not intuitive. Why not just have Three detect the change? For example, `obj.receiveShadow` could be a getter/setter, that can automatically modify `obj.material.needsUpdate`... or something...